How to find the angle of two opposite tangents of a circle that intersect at the same distant point
Good morning, first of all, I would like to ask permission to open a question here because I don't know where to search.
I'm trying to find a function that describes which opening angle gives the tangent of the circle's distance. I'm trying to make a generic code, I didn't want to put a table with angle/distance.
I don't know how to describe the problem correctly, I made an image trying to explain. I know this community isn't exactly for that, but I believe you have the answer.


Does this article help? I would use the formula for the spherical object.

"tangent of the circle's distance" does not parse even on the syntax level.

Maybe what you meant to ask is: Let $C$ be a circle centered at a point $O$, let $A, B$ be points on $C$. Let $\gamma$ denote the angle between the tangent lines to $C$ at  the points $A, B$. What is the formula for $\gamma$ in terms of the angle $\angle AOB$? This would be $\pi- \angle AOB$.

$$2\arcsin{1\over2n}$$

Let me try to give several answers. I'll use this diagram:

I think that you know the angle $u$ (or perhaps $2u$), or maybe the angle $h$ (or $2h$). There's also the radius $r$ of the circle, and the distance $d$ from the point $P$ to the center, $S$, of the circle.

Observation 1, due to @MoisheKohan:
$$
u + h + 90^{\circ} = 180^{\circ},
$$
so
$$
u = 90^{\circ} - h\\
2u = 180^{\circ} - 2h
$$

In other words, if you know the angle at $P$, you can find the angle at $S$, and vice-versa. This is independent of $d$ and $r$.

Suppose you know $r$ and $h$. Here's how to find $d$. We know that the triangle with red, yellow, and black sides is a right triangle (with the 90-degree angle being at the tangent point where green and yellow meet). So the sine of the angle at $P$ is opposite ($r$) over hypotenuse ($d$), i.e.
$$
\sin(u) = \frac{r}{d}
$$
so $d = \frac{r}{\sin(u)}$. But $\sin(u) = \cos(h)$, so we have $d = \frac{r}{\cos(h)}.$

Suppose you know $d$ and $r$, and want to find the angle $h$. From the previous answer, we have $d \cos (h) = r$, so $\cos(h) = \frac{r}{d}$, hence $h = \arccos(\frac{r}{d}).$ I'm not sure if you know much about things like "arccos", but it's what your calculator gives you when you press "INV" and then "COS".

Suppose you know $d$ and $r$ and want to find $u$. That's just $u = \arcsin(\frac{r}{d}).$


I can't think of anything else that you might be asking, but if I haven't answered what you really want, can you please express it in terms of the labels I've used on my picture?
